# I want to When have balance >0 then form not submit in php?

Tags: javascript, php

I want, If balance field is <0, If Recharge amount filed >0 then form not submit, Can you give me Java script or php code please. Here is my editing code but not working I dont understand. Please give me solutions

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

form.onsubmit = function(e){  
    if(document.getElementById("bal").value==30){
         e.preventDefault();
       alert("Value must not be equal to 30"); 
    }
    if(document.getElementById("bal").value<0){
         e.preventDefault();
       alert("error msg");
       return false; 
    }
    if(document.getElementById("amount").value>0){
         e.preventDefault();
       alert("error msg");
       return false; 
    }
};

</script>


</head>
<body>
<form action = '' method='post' name="recharge">
<input type="text" id="bal" name="bal" value="">Balance</><br>
<input type="text" id=="number" name="number" value="">Rehcarge number</><br>
<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" value="">Amount</><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apart from the answers suggesting JavaScript solutions – please be aware that you _have to_ validate those values server-side as well.

Comment: Yes, Anybody can tell me whats probelem in this code?

Comment: You got lots of answers already, so check those first.

Answer (score 0):

do in jquery like this

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(e){

if($("input[name=amount]").val() == "30")
{
alert("you have entered amount as 30. Form not submitted");
return false;
}
 else if($("input[name=amount]").val() > $("input[name=balance]").val())
{
alert("you dont have enough balance");
return false;
}
});
```

And Add this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

to head of html

Comment: I want if Balance to Recharge amount larger then not submit how to do this? Error to need show " You dont have balance".

Comment: @user3378277  you have to change the `name=balance` to `name=bal` because `bal` is the name given to your input in html.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

   jQuery("input[name='button']").click(function(e){

        //getting your balance amount
        bal = jQuery("input[name='balance']").val();

        //if balance is lesser than 0, form will be submitted
        if(bal<0){
         jQuery('form').submit();
       }
   });

});

</script>
```

Make sure your input fields are enclosed inside `<form></form>` tags.

Comment: @user3378277 What are you trying to do in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the submitted balance value like

```
$balance = $_REQUEST['balance']; if($balance <=30){     echo "cant submit form";    header("location: your form path ") ;    }
```

Or you can user jQuery to check the value and show alert message to user

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via javascript or using any of the js libraries, check on form submit as below:

Try

```
var form = document.getElementById("fr");
form.onsubmit = function(e){  
    if(document.getElementById("bal").value==30){
         e.preventDefault();
       alert("Value must not be equal to 30"); 
    }
    return true
};
```

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JJQxa/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    jQuery("input[name='submit']").click(function(e)
    {
       balance = jQuery("input[name='balance']").val();
       amount = jQuery("input[name='amount']").val();
       if(balance < 0 && amount > 0)
       {
         alert('Balance is less than 0 and amount is greater than 0 : So not submitting');
         jQuery('form').submit();
       }
       else
       {
           alert('Balance is greater than 0 : So not submitting');
       }
    });
});
</script>
<form action = '' method='post'>
    <input type="text" name="balance" value="">Balance</><br>
    <input type="text" name="number" value="">Rehcarge number</><br>
    <input type="text" name="amount" value="">Amount</><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

Comment: <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" onsubmit="?">